# Make a copy of a column of images omitting blank cells in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, images

I need to convert column A to column B (without blank cells between the flag images) using a formula.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use formulas to access some types of images, but not all.

If the images were imported with **Insert > Image in cell** or `image()` formulas, use one of these formulas to show the column without blanks:

`=filter(A1:A, not(isblank(A1:A)))`

`=filter(A1:A, not(isblank(A1:A)), not(istext(A1:A)), not(len(A1:A)))`

`=sort(A1:A)`

If the images were imported with **Insert > Image over cells**, they cannot be accessed with formulas.

Also note that some functions do not work well with images. For example, these formulas will *not* get the results you might expect:

> `=unique(A1:A)`
>
> `=query(A1:A)`
>
> `=vlookup("*", A1:A, 1, false)`

To detect whether a cell contains an image, use this formula:

`=1 = not(isblank(A1)) * not(istext(A1)) * not(len(A1))`